# float value binding to a textbox automatically removes dot if user deleted digits after decimal

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a textbox binded to a view model float property, On UI if i enter any value using dot and removing the digit after dot then dot gets automatically removed but i dont want this, if i used **StringFormat={}{##.##}** in binding (it worked) then it is not showing me default float value on UI which i want.

ViewModel

```
 public float Text
    {
        get { return this.text; }
        set
        {
            this.text = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }
```

xaml

Please revert as its on high priority :(

Answer (score 0):

The solution which i can suggest is to use a converter which take float as input and return its string value from the converter.

Comment: public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null) return 0;
            String a = ((float) value).ToString("0.0");
            return (a);
        }   
        Thanks i tried it already but on UI the default value its showing me (0.0) like a string format, but its behavior on UI is very much inconsistent for before decimal.